# How I can bypass the following error in botocore 3: Missing required header for this request: x-amz-content-sha256?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have the following script that upload a file into an s3 bucket:

```
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

s3_conf = {
  'bucket': 'the_bucketr',
  'folder': 'cohort',
  'config': Config(
    region_name = 'eu-central-1',
    signature_version = 'v4',
    retries = {
      'max_attempts': 10,
      'mode': 'standard'
  }),
  'aws_access_key_id':'^SOKE_KEY^',
  'aws_secret_access_key':'^NOT_TELLING_U^'
}

 s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
          config=s3_conf['config'],  
          aws_access_key_id=s3_conf['aws_access_key_id'],
          aws_secret_access_key=s3_conf['aws_secret_access_key']
      )

  s3_client.upload_file('loremIpsum.txt',s3_conf['bucket'],'loremUpsum.txt')
```

But I get the error:

```
Failed to upload loremIpsum.txt to the_bucketr/loremIpsum.txt: An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Missing required header for this request: x-amz-content-sha256
```

Do you have any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN order to bypass the problem you chould change the line

```
    signature_version = 'v4',
```

Into:

```
    signature_version = 's3v4',
```

And it will work like a well-oiled war machine.